# Set textcolor button back to default

Tags: android

I have a loginscreen.
In this loginscreen I have a button that is by default disabled.

When the user has entered 4 numbers I enable the button and change the textcolor to green.
But when the 4 numbers are not the correct code I clear my edittext and disable my button again.

At the moment the textcolor of this disabled button is offcourse green.
How can I set it back to the default color?

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() >= maxLength)
            {
                btnOk.setEnabled(true);
                btnOk.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00B32D"));
            }

            else
            {
                btnOk.setEnabled(false);
            }


private void checkIfValid(String inputPin)
{
    if(inputPin.equals("0000"))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowScreenActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        clearText();

      ====>   //Here i want to set my textcolor back to normal.  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Pincode foutief", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the default color of Button using this code,

```
int DefaultButtonColor = btnOk.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
```

If its not what you are looking for, then you can get Android Platform Resource Color using

something like,

```
android.R.color.secondary_text_dark
```

Check others too...

Comment: I already tried this, but this sets the button textcolor to black (like the button would be enabled). I need the white-like disabled color.

Comment: Yes, I know but my button is by default disabled. And the default disabled textcolor is white-like. (On my device at least, I don't know if this is device-dependent)

Comment: Did you try with `android.R.color.primary_text_dark` and other colors..?

Comment: like, `android.R.color.primary_text_dark_nodisable` , `android.R.color.primary_text_light`, `android.R.color.primary_text_light_nodisable` etc..

Comment: Thx! :) R.color.secondary_text_dark was the exact same color.

Comment: defaultColor is -65536 for me, so that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

Back up your default color in onCreate();

```
defaultTextColor = btnOk.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
```

Then set it back

```
btn.setTextColor(defaultTextColor);
```

Comment: This solution helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have another button that always maintains default color, you can set the color of your color-modified button to this other button to get back to default.  The code might be...

```
btnOk.setTextColor(btnCancel.getTextColors());
```

This is a simple one line solution, but you have to be careful the other button color is not being modified for other reasons or this may not work.